# Merge two or more ML models with different size of output togetger

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, softmax

I have several models that classify the input (word embedding) into several classes. My problem is that I need to train these models separately and need to merge the output of these models together to get a label.

For simplicity assume only two models:

```
Model 1: predicts A, B or C
Model 2: predicts D or E
```

Then, I need to classify the input X so that I get the joint probability over A, B, C, D and E.

I have tried this code in Keras/Python, in which I define neural networks and remove the softmax activation function after training:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=dim_in)
x = layers.Dense(dim_out)(inputs)
outputs = layers.Activation(activation="softmax")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='keras_model')
model_without_softmax = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs[0], outputs=model.layers[-2].output, name='keras_model', trainable=False)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

Then I get final prediction with softmax over joint arrays of predictions:

```
prediction = softmax(np.append(prediction_1, prediction_2))
```

It wasn't working because the output values from the neural networks were on a different scale when classifying into 2 or 3 classes. Thus, I tried dividing into a number of classes but without success:

```
prediction = softmax(np.append(prediction_1/len(idx2label_d1), prediction_2/len(idx2label_d2)))
```

Can you point me to right direction for the general formula of merging the neural network's outputs together?

Comment: After removing the softmax layer,  you can make a new model which encompasses both models for ABC and DE by connecting them to a single input layer. Then, you could take the outputs of the two models and concatenate them before applying a softmax. Let me know if you want me to post some code

Comment: But then I would need to train that joint ABC-DE model in a supervised way, right? I don't have an opportunity to see the labels for ABC in DE model and vice versa and in some cases I also need to opportunity to merge more than two models.

Comment: Oh, gotchu. Another thing you could do, though its not exactly what you're asking, is you can use a sigmoid function, then you end up with a OVR problem. The only other thing is you'd have to train with a garbage class.

Comment: So, I tried the performance with sigmoid activation at the end (and then softmax on joint prediction) - the result (f1 score) for my testing set was 0.68, if I use only one model (which is possible in my research environment) I got f1 score 0.88 - do you think that it is not possible to get closer to that one model score? And with the garbage class you mean something like solving Out-of-Domain problem, right?